# In convolutional neural network, what does fully-connected layer mean?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, unsupervised-learning, convolution

There are convolution layers, pooling layers, and possibly a classifier layer (e.g. softmax layer) in a convolutional neural network (CNN).

I heard that there is also a fully-connected layer. What is that?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/182122/103153

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every neuron from the previous layer is connected to every neuron on the next layer<sup>[1](https://pennlio.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/fully-connected-locally-connected-and-shared-weights-layer-in-neural-networks/)</sup>.

Answer (score 5):

The convolutional and the Pooling layers create a feature space, and the flatten FUlly connected layer can be thought as a cheap way of learning a linear function out of the feature space. For the convenience of understanding think of it as a PCA that selects the good features among the feature space created by the Conv and POOL layer.